# Returning a byte[] in WCF service

Tags: wcf

Is it a good practice to return a byte[] in a WCF service which will be invoked by many applications

below is the code

```
public byte[] GetDoc(string docParam)
{
    byte[] doc;
    doc = GenerateDoc(docParam);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good practice to factor common code into a convenient method so that many callers could call this convenient method.  This is regardless of return type.  If the callers would need to manipulate the `byte[]`, then this can become convenient and eliminate redundant code.

By the way, regarding the code that you posted, is that real code or just an example?  If it's real code:

1. It won't compile, because it doesn't return a `byte[]`.
2. If you were to call `return doc;` as the last line, why have `GenerateDoc()` inside `GetDoc()`? `GetDoc()` doesn't really provide any true benefit.

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely possible to return `byte[]` and WCF allows you to do this using MTOM encoding.

If the size of the binary buffer is big you could use [WCF streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731913.aspx). In this case you would return `Stream` data type, and read from that `Stream` on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

It's used when you want to transfer a binary buffer, and also perform Large Data Transfer using MTOM encoding (set on the Binding configuration). How to perform Large Data Transfer [found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).